# trigger insert only if tupel satisfies condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I want to create a trigger which checks before insert if the tupel which is supposed to be inserted holds a specific condition (which also depends on another table).

For example:

```sql
create trigger or replace check_tupel
before insert on A
for each row
execute
   if exists (select x,y from B where B.x = A.x and B.y = A.y)
```

Oh I am using postgreSQL 13.

EDIT: Yes I know that I can do this without a trigger, but I am asking for a solution with a trigger for a reason.

I hope there is a way to do this... My other idea was to create a UDF which gets called before insert but I do not know how to check the condition in this UDF and only insert if the function returns true.

Comment: What will you do `if the tupel which is supposed to be inserted holds a specific condition`?

Comment: Check the manual, create a trigger function (!) and then the trigger: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: I want to inser the tupel if it holds the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanna automatically validate a record before inserting it on table `A` based on table `B` using a User Defined Function, you do not need a trigger at all. Consider adding a simple [`CHECK CONSTRAINT`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-check-constraint/):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  x int,
  y int,
 CONSTRAINT exists_in_b CHECK (NOT myfunc(x,y))
);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa29bb224c02c8e9d3be3ca059c692a2)

```
CREATE TABLE b (x int,
                y int);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (42,42);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(x int, y int) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
 SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.y =$1 AND b.x=$2 )
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE TABLE a (
  x int,
  y int,
 CONSTRAINT exists_in_b CHECK (NOT myfunc(x,y)) -- here the magic happens
);
```

Now, if we try to insert a value that our function does not validate, it raises an exception:

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (42,42);

ERROR:  new row for relation "a" violates check constraint "exists_in_b"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (42, 42).
SQL state: 23514
```

**EDIT** (See comments): Solution using a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.y =NEW.y AND b.x=NEW.x ) THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'tuple already exists in "b": % %', NEW.x,NEW.y;
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_tupel
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON a
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myfunc();
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=beb7d00d71cec0c3edfddc5fb25db4c8)

Comment: that is a really nice solution, but I asked for one using a trigger for a reason.

Comment: @maba I see. So perhaps my last edit might help you

Answer (score 0):

So you need a trigger solution, sounds like a homework problem. The question then becomes do you want to:

1. abort the entire operation
2. slightly squash the row but continue the remainder of the operation.

The following does the second: (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0eebfd9a2454c608d82e30cfb4d9c1bd))

```
create or replace 
function check_b_has_a() 
 returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    if exists 
        ( select null 
            from b 
           where (b.x,b.y) = 
                 (new.x, new.y)
        ) 
    then 
       return null; 
    else 
       return new; 
    end if;
end; 
$$; 

create trigger a_bir
   before insert 
       on a 
      for each row 
      execute function check_b_has_a();
```